# How to put PHP file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

How do I put PHP file in JavaScript. I want to replace awesome font used inside JavaScript with icon that has been created its function to be called.

I want to put this file:

```
<img class="svgbeloved" src="<?php echo Wo_GetSvg('microphone'); ?>">
```

to replace the awesome fonts that are in JavaScript:

```js
function Wa_CleanRecordNodes(){
  $(".record-comment-audio").each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).html('<i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>').attr('data-record', '0');
    $('[data-comment-rtime="'+$(el).attr('id')+'"]').text('00:00').addClass('hidden');
  });
```

And I have tried this, but it did not work:

```js
function Wa_CleanRecordNodes(){
  $(".record-comment-audio").each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).html('<img class="svgbeloved" src="<?php echo Wo_GetSvg('microphone'); ?>">').attr('data-record', '0');
    $('[data-comment-rtime="'+$(el).attr('id')+'"]').text('00:00').addClass('hidden');
  });
```

Comment: You cant place Php code in JavaScript files. You need to write your Php code in a Php file and use it to output JavaScript/HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
 let src = <?php echo json_encode(Wo_GetSvg('microphone')); ?>;
```

And then use that variable. Other ways you can do that is to use axios, cookie or VueJS and pass data into component. Hope that helps.